# Is there a way to configure Nginx to broadcast incoming requests to multiple upstream servers simultaneously?

Tags: nginx

The following fragment will pick one server at a time. Is there a way to hit them all at once?

```
upstream backend {
    server 17.0.0.1:8000;
    server 17.0.0.1:8001;
    server 17.0.0.1:8002;
    server 17.0.0.1:8003;

}

server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to send the same request to all 4 instances? Then they will all answer. I don't think it is possible in *nginx*, but the code change shouldn't be that hard to cope with that behavior.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a solution using [ngx_http_mirror_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mirror_module.html) (available since nginx 1.13.4):

```
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://17.0.0.1:8000;
        mirror /s1;
        mirror /s2;
        mirror /s3;       
    }
    location /s1 { internal; proxy_pass http://17.0.0.1:8001$request_uri; }
    location /s2 { internal; proxy_pass http://17.0.0.1:8002$request_uri; }
    location /s3 { internal; proxy_pass http://17.0.0.1:8003$request_uri; }
}
```

nginx will:

- send the same request to all servers
- wait for all of them to finish
- respond with the http://17.0.0.1:8000 response (and ignore the others)

Comment: The only way I could make this solution work is to setup upstreams for each one of my backends, then use the upstream for the proxy_pass, as explained here: https://alex.dzyoba.com/blog/nginx-mirror/

Answer (score 3):

If you've built nginx with the Lua module (or you're using OpenResty), the following snippet will allow you to broadcast a response to all servers in an upstream group.

Requests are made in parallel, and once they have completed it will return the individual HTTP responses and response headers.

```
upstream @api {
    server  10.0.0.1:80;
    server  10.0.0.2:80 backup;
}

server {
    server_name _;
    listen 443 ssl;

    location ~ ^/broadcast(?<proxy_path>/.*)$ {
        lua_need_request_body on;

        content_by_lua '
            local upstream = require "ngx.upstream"
            local servers = upstream.get_servers("@api")

            local requests = {}
            for _, srv in ipairs(servers) do
                local addr = srv.addr
                table.insert(requests, { "/proxy", { method = ngx["HTTP_" .. ngx.var.request_method], always_forward_body = true, copy_all_vars = true, vars = { proxy_host = addr } } })
            end

            local responses = { ngx.location.capture_multi(requests) }
            for i, res in ipairs(responses) do
                local addr = servers[i].addr
                ngx.say(addr, " HTTP/1.1 ", res.status)
                for header, value in pairs(res.header) do
                    ngx.say(header, ": ", value)
                end
                ngx.say()
                ngx.print(res.body)
                ngx.say()
            end
        ';
    }

    location /proxy {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://$proxy_host$proxy_path$is_args$args;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is also shown in a bit more context here: https://gist.github.com/RavenZZ/667fb1a06de18f20bea946f276937847 Very neat. :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation today and wanted to broadcast a GET against a number of my servers that are listening on APIs to trigger git pulls.  I couldn't find anything in Nginx to handle this sort of behavior and I didn't want to jump to writing an extension just yet.

Instead, I hacked together something using Python's Flask and Requests modules:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

# add whatever you need here to the methods
@app.route("/http/replay/<method>", methods=["POST", "GET", "PUT", "OPTIONS"])
def http_replay(method):
    """Replay an incoming request of type <method> against the parameter list of endpoints"""

    endpoint_list = request.args.get("host", "")
    endpoint_list = endpoint_list.split(";")
    timeout = request.args.get("timeout", None) or 5

    if not endpoint_list:
        return jsonify(status=500,
                       message="Expected parameters in the form of ?host=http://host/path;host=http://host2/path")
    else:

        responses = []
        for ep in endpoint_list:
            try:
                _r = requests.__getattribute__(method.lower())(ep, timeout=timeout)

                status_code = _r.status_code
            except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
                status_code = 408  # request timeout
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
                status_code = 520

            responses.append(status_code)

        _r_status = set(responses)

        if len(_r_status) == 1 and _r_status.pop == 200:
            status = 200
        else:
            status = 520

        return jsonify(status=status)
```

This simply listens on a path and allows me to send a request, such as:

```
curl "http://localhost:5000/plugins/http/replay/POST?host=http://localhost:80/api;host=http://dev.localhost:8080/api?timeout=10"
```

and returns an HTTP 200 status code if all the endpoints in the URL parameters did the same.

Comment: You're assuming that the client knows the list of proxies.