# Is it possible to execute specific requests to all load balancing upstream server?

Tags: nginx

I'm using NGINX server to proxying HTTP request and load balancing request to multiple upstream servers. But I have a specific requirement to execute specific request to all upstream servers.

Is it possible using NGINX load balancing?

I am using below nginx configurations

```
http {
    upstream myapp1 {
        server srv1.example.com;
        server srv2.example.com;
        server srv3.example.com;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://myapp1;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a specific request (/update) like below which needs to get executed in all upstream servers and all other request than (/update) should get executed as per load balancing strategy.

```
http {
    upstream myapp1 {
        server srv1.example.com;
        server srv2.example.com;
        server srv3.example.com;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location /update {
            proxy_pass http://myapp1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is useful. [Is there a way to configure Nginx to broadcast incoming requests to multiple upstream servers simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22948017/is-there-a-way-to-configure-nginx-to-broadcast-incoming-requests-to-multiple-ups)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such provison to broadcast request in nginx.

There are two options in my mind  to achieve this

1. Create seperate service that will execute given operation on all servers.
   e.g create one php file update.php on any of your applicatin server or host it on nginx server itself and make curl request 
   or send request  to all upstream servers.

update.php

```
<?php
file_get_contents("srv1.example.com/update");
file_get_contents("srv2.example.com/update");
file_get_contents("srv3.example.com/update");
?>
```

Above script just hit request to serveres if you want to post data you can use curl.

```
http {
    upstream myapp1 {
        server srv1.example.com;
        server srv2.example.com;
        server srv3.example.com;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://myapp1;
        }


        location /update {
            proxy_pass "http://servername/update.php";
        }

    }
}
```

2. Use nginx lua module which provide 
   ngx.location.capture_multi and  ngx.location.capture functions to send request to all required urls.

https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxlocationcapture_multi

Comment: Here what should be the value of "url to update all servers" ?

Comment: It is path to service which will update all your servers .  May be a php script on nginx server itself or one of your application server which manually make curl request to all upstream servers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a working Lua block that can achieve this

```
upstream @api {
    server  10.0.0.1:80;
    server  10.0.0.2:80 backup;
}

server {
    server_name _;
    listen 443 ssl;

    location ~ ^/broadcast(?<proxy_path>/.*)$ {
        lua_need_request_body on;

        content_by_lua '
            local upstream = require "ngx.upstream"
            local servers = upstream.get_servers("@api")

            local requests = {}
            for _, srv in ipairs(servers) do
                local addr = srv.addr
                table.insert(requests, { "/proxy", { method = ngx["HTTP_" .. ngx.var.request_method], always_forward_body = true, copy_all_vars = true, vars = { proxy_host = addr } } })
            end

            local responses = { ngx.location.capture_multi(requests) }
            for i, res in ipairs(responses) do
                local addr = servers[i].addr
                ngx.say(addr, " HTTP/1.1 ", res.status)
                for header, value in pairs(res.header) do
                    ngx.say(header, ": ", value)
                end
                ngx.say()
                ngx.print(res.body)
                ngx.say()
            end
        ';
    }

    location /proxy {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://$proxy_host$proxy_path;
    }

}
```