# How to configure nginx to broadcast message to multiple urls

Tags: nginx, broadcast

**How can I broadcast a request coming to one url to multiple other urls, using nginx?** Ex -

*If the request comes to https://mywebshop.com/rest/V1/masterDataImport, it should broadcast it further to the same endpoint https://mywebshop.com/rest/V1/masterDataImport as well as to https://mywebshop1.com/rest/V1/masterDataImport, https://mywebshop2.com/rest/V1/masterDataImport*

**Or Any other suggestion to achieve this using any other tech, may be some messaging queues.**

Comment: You will find this Useful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22948017/is-there-a-way-to-configure-nginx-to-broadcast-incoming-requests-to-multiple-ups

Comment: Thanks, this is resolved.